# d3js - the path is not drawing full values while using `defined`

Tags: d3.js

I am getting data from back-end like this: (the data has `0` values. so I am preventing those values from draw lines.)

```
[{"ActualPercentage":5.5,"PlanPercentage":10,"Week":"\/Date(1438376400000+0300)\/","WeeklyActual":0,"WeeklyPlan":0},
{"ActualPercentage":10.5,"PlanPercentage":15,"Week":"\/Date(1441054800000+0300)\/","WeeklyActual":0,"WeeklyPlan":0},
{"ActualPercentage":15,"PlanPercentage":20,"Week":"\/Date(1443646800000+0300)\/","WeeklyActual":0,"WeeklyPlan":0},
{"ActualPercentage":24.129,"PlanPercentage":30,"Week":"\/Date(1446325200000+0300)\/","WeeklyActual":0,"WeeklyPlan":0},
{"ActualPercentage":27.3,"PlanPercentage":31,"Week":"\/Date(1448917200000+0300)\/","WeeklyActual":0,"WeeklyPlan":0},
{"ActualPercentage":30.5,"PlanPercentage":33.014,"Week":"\/Date(1451595600000+0300)\/","WeeklyActual":0,"WeeklyPlan":0},
{"ActualPercentage":33,"PlanPercentage":36.532,"Week":"\/Date(1454274000000+0300)\/","WeeklyActual":0,"WeeklyPlan":0},
{"ActualPercentage":0,"PlanPercentage":41.246,"Week":"\/Date(1456779600000+0300)\/","WeeklyActual":0,"WeeklyPlan":0},
{"ActualPercentage":0,"PlanPercentage":44.781,"Week":"\/Date(1459458000000+0300)\/","WeeklyActual":0,"WeeklyPlan":0},
{"ActualPercentage":0,"PlanPercentage":48.316,"Week":"\/Date(1462050000000+0300)\/","WeeklyActual":0,"WeeklyPlan":0},
{"ActualPercentage":0,"PlanPercentage":53.03,"Week":"\/Date(1464728400000+0300)\/","WeeklyActual":0,"WeeklyPlan":0},
{"ActualPercentage":0,"PlanPercentage":57.158,"Week":"\/Date(1467320400000+0300)\/","WeeklyActual":0,"WeeklyPlan":0},
{"ActualPercentage":0,"PlanPercentage":60.148,"Week":"\/Date(1469998800000+0300)\/","WeeklyActual":0,"WeeklyPlan":0},
{"ActualPercentage":0,"PlanPercentage":64.868,"Week":"\/Date(1472677200000+0300)\/","WeeklyActual":0,"WeeklyPlan":0},
{"ActualPercentage":0,"PlanPercentage":69.528,"Week":"\/Date(1475269200000+0300)\/","WeeklyActual":0,"WeeklyPlan":0},
{"ActualPercentage":0,"PlanPercentage":73.653,"Week":"\/Date(1477947600000+0300)\/","WeeklyActual":0,"WeeklyPlan":0},
{"ActualPercentage":0,"PlanPercentage":78.956,"Week":"\/Date(1480539600000+0300)\/","WeeklyActual":0,"WeeklyPlan":0},
{"ActualPercentage":0,"PlanPercentage":84.053,"Week":"\/Date(1483218000000+0300)\/","WeeklyActual":0,"WeeklyPlan":0},
{"ActualPercentage":0,"PlanPercentage":88.392,"Week":"\/Date(1485896400000+0300)\/","WeeklyActual":0,"WeeklyPlan":0},
{"ActualPercentage":0,"PlanPercentage":93.119,"Week":"\/Date(1488315600000+0300)\/","WeeklyActual":0,"WeeklyPlan":0},
{"ActualPercentage":0,"PlanPercentage":97.605,"Week":"\/Date(1490994000000+0300)\/","WeeklyActual":0,"WeeklyPlan":0},
{"ActualPercentage":0,"PlanPercentage":98,"Week":"\/Date(1493586000000+0300)\/","WeeklyActual":0,"WeeklyPlan":0},
{"ActualPercentage":0,"PlanPercentage":100,"Week":"\/Date(1496264400000+0300)\/","WeeklyActual":0,"WeeklyPlan":0}]
```

to prevent the drawing unwanted values i am using `defined` like this:

```
var line = d3.svg.line()
                // .interpolate("basis")
                .defined(function(d) { return d.temperature })
                .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
                .y(function(d) { return y(d.temperature); });
```

But i am not getting the path properly drawn. see here the picture:

[image]

Actually the green line has to draw up to the top. and the red line is correct here. what is wrong with my approach?

what is the correct way to draw the lines then?

**Update**
if  I comment this line the graph works fine:

```
 // path
                 //      .attr("stroke-dasharray", totalLength + " " + totalLength)
                 //      .attr("stroke-dashoffset", totalLength)
                 //      .transition()
                 //      .duration(2000)
                 //      .ease("linear")
                 //      .attr("stroke-dashoffset", 0);
```

Comment: can u put this up on a fiddle

Comment: cyril, if you want i am ready to share my code. but I can't able to reproduce with jsfiddle

Comment: @Cyril here is the full code in js file ; http://plnkr.co/edit/8FaZ1F3kFlcWbJEHjqGh?p=info

Comment: I don't see any issues i changed your data set to have 0 and it works fine.. http://plnkr.co/edit/xt7i8ip1d7fjxYw3KCN6?p=preview correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: @Cyril - But I am using the same approach. please find my js code. But not working. can you find the wrong what i do in js file? ( see my 2nd comment  for full code )

Comment: @Cyril - I guess the issue is there in commented area with your plnkr

Comment: which comment add and send back...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107839/discussion-between-user2024080-and-cyril).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update the way you are calculating total length:

```
var totalLength = [path[0][0].getTotalLength()];
```

you should do

```
var totalLength = d3.max(path[0], function(d1){return d1.getTotalLength()});
```

So that you can set the maximum length to the `stroke-dashoffset`

working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/xt7i8ip1d7fjxYw3KCN6?p=preview)